# Checking if I'm correct about the order of operations in Bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection, command, string, echo

Guten Tag! I'm a rookie in everything Bash-related. I'm familiarizing with the syntax and wanted to know if the order of operations in this command is as I thought or not.

The command:
`echo 2 * 3 > 5 is a valid inequality` from Learning The Bash Shell by Cameron Newham

I believe the order is as follows:

1. `echo` is interpreted
2. `2` is read and buffered
3. `*` is interpreted, and a search is initialized
4. Every matching file in the current folder is appended to buffer
5. `3` is read and buffered
6. `> 5` is interpreted, and a new file `5` is created, and also redirecting output
7. `is` is read and buffered
8. `a` is read and buffered
9. `valid` is read and buffered
10. `inequality` is read and buffered
11. `echo` outputs content in buffer to `5`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

I'm not going to read the bash source code, but I doubt it happens as you imagine, simply because most reasonably sophisticated interpreters don't execute things while interpreting, they read the entire statement, figure it out, and then execute. They don't read one symbol like 5, create a file, and then continue reading and "buffering".

What you do need to know (sometimes) is the order of bash's processing: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, command substitution; word splitting; filename expansion; process substitution.

Which kind of answers your question... since word splitting is one of the final phases, not the first phase, it can hardly be creating files in the midst of reading the text.

bash is a lot more complicated to understand in its fine details than most people imagine... which is not a good thing. It's an esoteric mishmash of things that could probably do with a full redesign. But it is what it is.

Comment: One other thing, you can download the source code to various old unix shells, like this one here... https://v6sh.org/src/sh.c  .. which is only a few pages long. But even these old simple shells did all the parsing and reading of the command before they actually executed it. You can get a bit of an idea what happens inside a shell from a few pages of code.

Comment: word splitting is what happens to results of expansions, it's not something that's relevant for the parsing of the command line, or recognizing redirections. There are no expansions here, so also no word splitting